# Debugging Silverlight XAML errors on Line 1 at design time

Tags: silverlight, xaml

In a Silverlight app, we are getting a huge number of errors at design time in a XAML ResourceDictionary file (VS 2013 Update 2, SL 5).  These all seem to imply that our styles are using properties that aren't defined for the type, but I can't see any way to track down which styles are causing the issue (there are about 100 styles in this file).

The member "RowIndicatorVisibility" is not recognized or is not accessible. 
The member "Template" is not recognized or is not accessible.
The member "VerticalAlignment" is not recognized or is not accessible
The member "VerticalContentAlignment" is not recognized or is not accessible.

The issue is all of these errors simply refer to line 1, column 1 of the XAML resource file.  Is there any way to get better debugging support?  At runtime none of these problems are present and we run without errors, but it makes developing difficult since there are so many errors cluttering up the list.

Comment: do you have any code with you?

Comment: Did you recently bump up to SL5 from SL4?

Comment: @Sajeetharan The file is over 5000 lines!  That's part of the problem.  It's not an easy matter of just swapping a few things out.  I could post the namespaces, but I'm not sure that would help much.

Comment: @ChrisW. We did upgrade to SL5 a few months ago.  I don't remember if we had this issue before that.  Would that point to anything?

Comment: If you've highly modified your templates and are currently using them to override the SDK defaults, then ya you're going to likely run into this.

Comment: Well I'm not surprised I'm having a problem!  My problem is that I can't troubleshoot it when all of the errors say they occur in Line 1, Column 1!  I'm looking for a way to narrow down the location of the errors better.  Can I get better errors out of the XAML compiler somehow?